# Filter Web Page

Tags: php, mysql, filter, html

I have a webpage that displays a query of complete list of names like this:

```
First Name  Last Name
====================================
Aarn        Kreadon
Aaron       Czetli
Aaron       Balan
Aaron       Franken
Aaron       O'Neil
Aaron       Barnair
Abbey       Chua
Abner       Marasigan
...etc      ...etc
```

I also have a selector on the same page that looks like this:

```
Browse by first name.
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I - J - K - L - M - N - O - P - Q - R - S - T - U - V - W - X - Y - Z 

Browse by last name.
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I - J - K - L - M - N - O - P - Q - R - S - T - U - V - W - X - Y - Z
```

How can I filter the list of names based on the "first name" or "last name" selected?

Do I need to have a separate page for each letter?

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect to mysql server');
  }

  mysql_select_db("thepoolscene", $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblPlayers");

  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>

  </tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
  }

  echo "</table>";

  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways to do this.  The classic way would be to modify the SQL statement to

```
SELECT * FROM tblPlayers where First_Name LIKE 'A%'
```

The above example would get all players with a first name beginning with A

Each A-Z link would link to the same page but with an added $_GET variable such as http://url/file.php?fname=a

The second way and more 'modern' way would probably be to use the same query above but return the array in JSON and fetch it with AJAX.  Then you can do all your filtering with the array in javascript.  Which is cool cause you don't have to refresh the page and it's almost instant.